# Solution of this type Of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y = x(y')^2 + (y')^3$$
I could'nt find any youtube videos related to to this type of ODE.
Could you brielfly explain what the things are needed to solve this question.

Comment: This's a D'Alembert equation.

Comment: Did you try  substituiting $y^{\prime}=p=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$? then derivative respect to x

Comment: I dont know using this method. I dont know what I should do. I dont know this type of ODEs to solve. Nothing I know...

Comment: @johnsonhere Please, read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation